# How divide a string into array

Tags: c#, json

If I have the following plain string, how do I divide it into an array of three elements?

```
{["a","English"],["b","US"],["c","Chinese"]}

["a","English"],["b","US"],["c","Chinese"]
```

This problem is related to JSON string parsing, so I wonder if there is any API to facilitate the conversion.

Comment: there a lot of JSON frameworks for .net, sorry I have not done JSON for a few years, so I don't know witch framework to point you at these day.  However you should not have to be doing your own string processing for JSON!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a little console example using regex there is most likely a better way to do it.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "{[\"a\",\"English\"],[\"b\",\"US\"],[\"c\",\"Chinese\"]}";
        foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match m in System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(str, @"((\[.*?\]))"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Captures[0]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @rerun: I saw ur solution most suiting my current situation. Could elaborate more on the match pattern? I'm not aware of Regex. Thx.

Comment: Regex is a big topic but basicly its a way of shorthand text matching and capturing. the match string I provided match all characters between [] and stores them in a capture.  take a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html it has a ton of great info.

Comment: Thx. What's the double parentheses means?

Comment: You'll need a better regex than that if your strings ever contain '[' or ']' characters.  Or as Jamie Zawinski put it in his famous quote from 1997 "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems." 

DataContract serialization is a better bet.

Answer (score 2):

use DataContract serialization http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC comes [with methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.json.aspx) for easily converting collections to JSON format. There is also the [JavaScriptSerializer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) in `System.Web.Script.Serialization`. Lastly there is also a good 3rd party library by James Newton called [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the curly braces then use String.Split, with ',' as the separator.

Unfortunately, I never did JSON stuff so don't know a parsing library. Can't you let WCF do this stuff for you ?

Answer (score 0):

using String.Split won't work on a single token as the string in each token also contain a string (if I understood the requirements, the array elements should end up being:

1. ["a","English"]
2. ["b","US"]
3. ["c","Chinese"]

If you use string.Split and use a comma as the delimiter the array will be made up of:

1. ["a"
2. "English"]
3. ["b"
4. "US"]
5. ["c"
6. "Chinese"]

A JSON parser that I've read about but never used is available here:

http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx